# Why am i getting syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to implement a linux command using a shell script to delete some files & directories from a directory ignoring "output.mp4" & "_Removed.avi" but getting the following Error :

```
./test.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.sh: line 11: `sudo rm -rf !("output.mp4"|"_Removed.avi")'
```

Script That i am implementing is :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d /home/Videos_bkp/ ]
then

cd /home/subham/Videos_bkp

sudo rm -rf !("output.mp4"|"_Removed.avi")

else

echo "Directory Not Available"

fi
```

Comment: If you want to use the extended glob pattern matching operators (like `!(...)`) you must first enable the `extglob` bash option (`shopt -s extglob`), if it is not already enabled. Note: you test the existence of directory `/home/Videos_bkp/` but you work in directory `/home/subham/Videos_bkp`. This is probably an error. Note: you don't need to `cd` in a directory to access its content. `!("/home/subham/Videos_bkp/output.mp4"|"/home/subham/Videos_bkp/_Removed.avi")` would work the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this type of script. I created this to delete file and folders exculding some folders thats why I used [-maxdepth 1] followed by folder names but you can use file name as well.

````
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -d  /home/Videos_bkp/ ]];
then

cd /home/subham/Videos_bkp

find . -maxdepth 1  ! -name "output.mp4" ! -name "_Removed.avi" ! -name . -exec rm -r {} \;

else

echo "Directory Not Available"

fi```
````

Comment: When you call `rm` after a `cd`, make sure the `cd` succeeded. In this code `/home/Videos_bkp/` and `/home/subham/Videos_bkp` are different, so running this script can go really wrong. Do something like `cd /home/subham/Videos_bkp || exit 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The subshell needs to open `extglob`. Add the following content to the header of the file.

```
shopt -s extglob
...
```

Answer (score 0):

File Name sould like `*.bash` & run `bash *.bash` in your terminal
The subshell needs to open extglob. Add the following content to the header of the file. `shopt` not running in sh. so, you need to run with bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
cd /home/subham/Videos_bkp
sudo rm -v !("output.mp4"|"_Removed.avi")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).